# Are Unity Web Games susceptible to Cross site scripting

Tags: javascript, html, xss, unity-webgl

Specifically for Unity games compiled for the web.

As Unity's web exporter targets HTML5, does this make it open to XSS attack. Let's say for example there is a multiplayer game where users can enter and save text that will be viewed by all players in the game. Would a malicious user be able to inject some javascript that would then execute in all the clients running the game that can see the entered text?

Comment: XSS is only possible when you load HTML templates with unsanitized user input and send the resulting HTML to clients. If user input is only being rendered and not executed, there shouldn't be any problem. Keep in mind that, in this sense, browsers _execute_ HTML, but browsers can't "execute" something rendered through WebGL. Just don't do something stupid like injecting unsanitized user input into a WebGL shader.

Comment: this question has absolutely nothing to do with WebGL. The questioner is using Unity's extremely poor naming choice for Unity's feature of exporting to HTML5 and so pretty much every question about that export path is mis-tagged on SO and the questioner has no clue that their terms are wrong. The XSS issues for games exported from Unity to HTML5 are no different than any other HTML5 page. No more, no less.

Comment: @gman thanks for clarifying, as I understand it, Unity's web games are built on top of WebGL, and you are correct in assuming that my question was more focused towards unity. I will edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: Unity's web games are buikd on top of HTML5. Unity incorrectly called tbat WebGL. Unity web games use the features of HTML5 inuding Web Audio, Web Assembly, the GamePad API, JavaScript, the Fullscreen API, the Pointer Lock API, The Blob API, the XMLHTTPRequest API , the WebGL API, and other APIs all part of HTML5. If Unity actually exported to WebGL then it could not load files,nor play sounds, nor take user input from mouse, keyboard, touch screen, gamepad etc since WebGL does none of those things

Answer (score 0):

the answer highly depends on how your server is setup but in general, any data you send to server and process without sanitising will make it open to XSS attack. Again it is down to what you do with that data but it is good practice to sanitise your data all the time. nothing too specific to WebGL here unless you are running a WebGL instance in your server to process that data.

Comment: I think one point would be to avoid creating shaders using strings pieced together from user input since that could be a potential attack vector gaining direct access to the GPU if there are any vulnerabilities in the WebGL implementation.

Comment: if you can cross script then you can do anything you want. that means creating your own WebGL context or Audio context or worker threads etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in a way. If you allow unsanitized code into your webpage, whether JS or WebGL shaders or anything, it can and will execute and exploit your users.

That being said, I've never heard of WebGL being used in an XSS. In some ways probably because its somewhat easier (and people have been doing it for longer) to inject a little script onto a page than to get a full shader up and running. And much more importantly, XSS attacks are usually about *stealing* information from users, or making them automatically 'take actions' they didn't authorize doing, or similar. Using a ton of GPU power just isn't that useful for accomplishing the goals of the XSS hacker.

If we ever do see WebGL used in an XSS attack, I'm guessing it will probably be a cryptomining scheme, as that is one of the few things that would benefit from the type of processing power a GPU has.

---

To mitigate this, like all XSS, **sanitize, sanitize, sanitize!** Make sure at no step from client to server back to client can what the user input in that box execute anything on its own, Javascript, SQL, WebGL, nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure who is aggressively down voting every answer this question has ever received, but if you have a better answer or suggestions to how we could improve our answers, I'd love to hear them.